# R dnorm result different between standardized and unstandardized values

Tags: r, statistics, numerical-methods, normal-distribution

I ran into a confusing situation when calculating normal distribution density in `R` using standardized value vs. unstandardized value:

```
ds <- function(x, mu, var) {dnorm(x, mean = mu, sd = sqrt(var))}
ds1 <- function(x, mu, var) {dnorm((x-mu)/sqrt(var), mean = 0, sd = 1)}
```

These two should give identical results. However, they don't:

```
> ds(0, 1, 2)
[1] 0.2196956
> ds1(0, 1, 2)
[1] 0.3106966
```

It appears that it might be because of the numerical differences caused by both `sqrt` and `dnorm`, because if I set `var = 1`, then the result is identical:

```
> ds(0, 1, 1)
[1] 0.2419707
> ds1(0, 1, 1)
[1] 0.2419707
> ds1(0, 1, 1.001)
[1] 0.2420916
> ds(0, 1, 1.001)
[1] 0.2419707
```

Could anyone point out what is the reason for this?

Comment: They shouldn't be the same. End of statement. Seriously though this is a misunderstanding you have about densities versus probabilities and not a programming question so it doesn't belong here. (But it's true - they shouldn't be the same)

Comment: I think you may be confusing `dnorm` and `pnorm`. If you replace the former  with the latter in your example, both functions return the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ds1`, you have forgotten `1/sqrt(var)` term:

```
ds1 <- function(x, mu, var) {dnorm((x-mu)/sqrt(var), mean = 0, sd = 1)/sqrt(var)}

> ds(1,2,3)
[1] 0.1949697
> ds1(1,2,3)
[1] 0.1949697
```

Comment: Thanks. I figured that a few hours later. And thanks those that point out that I misunderstood probability and density. I might be a little shaky in the concepts, but the reason here is that I forgot the Jacobian.